# Adding Trip Index in trip.js

Tags: javascript

I am making a tour of a website by using trip.js. The navigation that it provides shows "Next" and "Previous". I am trying to find out a way to show numbering of each step, and also the total steps.

Something similar to intro.js where it shows the current step number.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am the author of Trip.js,

in version 2.0.1, you can put {{tripIndex}} on the title, please check http://eragonj.github.io/Trip.js/demo-basic.html#theme-demo for more information.

And you just mentioned a good idea, I think I can extend this functionality to all possible places that users can put their own contents.

Comment: Can't wait for the extended functionality.